# Bresenham’s line drawing algorithm to hightlight boxes

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm looking for this behaviour http://www.brainjunkie.com/web/js-wordsearch/ but with this boxes:

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  cursor: pointer;
}

div.selected,
div:hover {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div>A</div>
<div>B</div>
<div>C</div>
```

I want be able to click in one box, then drag and change the color of the other boxes two.

I have made a previous post, but the accept answer (i didn't realize when i accepted doesn't work well for me, since i'm looking for the exactly behaviour in the link above.

Thank you.

Comment: It's really not clear what you're asking.

Comment: I updated the question.

Comment: What exactly does changing the color of a box have to do with Bresenham's line-drawing algorithm?

Comment: Cause the guy in the link is using it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
For Bresenham’s Line Generation
Assumptions :
1) Line is drawn from left to right.
2) x1 < x2 and y1< y2
3) Slope of the line is between 0 and 1.
   We draw a line from lower left to upper
   right.
```

```js
var x1, y1, x2, y2;
    function handleMouseDown(e){
          x1 = +e.target.dataset.x;
          y1 = +e.target.dataset.y;
          
          container.addEventListener('mousemove', handleMouseMove);      
          e.preventDefault();
    }
    function handleMouseMove(e){
          x2 = +e.target.dataset.x;
          y2 = +e.target.dataset.y;
          
          var ele = document.querySelectorAll('[data-x][data-y]');
          ele.forEach(function(val){
              val.classList.remove('selected')
          });

          bresenham(x1, y1, x2, y2);     
          
          
    }
    function handleMouseUp(e){
        var ele = document.querySelectorAll('[data-x][data-y]');
        ele.forEach(function(val){
            val.classList.remove('selected')
        });
        e.preventDefault();
        container.removeEventListener('mousemove', handleMouseMove);      
    }
    function bresenham(x1 , y1, x2 , y2){

         var m_new = 2 * (y2 - y1);
         var slope_error_new = m_new - (x2 - x1);
         for (var x = x1, y = y1; x <= x2; x++)
         {
             var ele = document.querySelector('[data-x="'+x+'"][data-y="'+y+'"]');
             ele.classList.add('selected');     
            // Add slope to increment angle formed
            slope_error_new += m_new;
       
            // Slope error reached limit, time to
            // increment y and update slope error.
            if (slope_error_new >= 0)
            {
               y++;
               slope_error_new  -= 2 * (x2 - x1);
            }
         }
    }
    var container = document.getElementById('container');
    container.addEventListener('mousedown', handleMouseDown);
    container.addEventListener('mouseup', handleMouseUp);
```

```css
div {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  div.selected{
    background-color: red;
    color: white;
  }
```

```html
<span id="container">
     <div data-x="0" data-y="0" >A</div>
     <div data-x="1" data-y="0" >B</div>
     <div data-x="2" data-y="0" >C</div>
</span>
```